# TimeSpan or DateTime for hour and minute as parameters to parse into Ticks

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, date

I have a form that has two inputs for time:

1. First represents hours, maxlength is 3 and accepts only ints.
2. Second represents minutes, maxlength is 2 and regex mask to max value of 59.

```html
<input type="text" id="timeHour" name="timeHour" class="form-control" placeholder="000" maxlength="3" />

<input type="text" id="timeMinute" name="timeMinute" class="form-control" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" />
```

Its used to register the amount of time a user worked in a certain task.
For example, I work 100 hours and 15 minutes, I'll enter 100 in the first input
and 15 in the second.

In my ActionResult timeHour and timeMinute comes as strings.

I want to get the hours and minutes sum them and then parse it to Ticks.

Which is the best date object to use?

Comment: I'm confused, sure you don't want a `TimeSpan` and not a `DateTime`? It makes no sense to have three digits if not.

Comment: So you could theoretically enter `999` hours?

Comment: So what would the date be if I entered `999` hours? Right now plus 999 hours?

Comment: @Leo: what does `999` hours translate to? This is a timespan... DateTime is more calendar related data, not timespan. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think you want to do `Convert.ToDateTime`, I think you want a `int hour = Convert.ToInt32(dateTimeHour); int minute = ...` then a `var time = new TimeSpan(0, hour, minute)`

Comment: Also, what does `new DateTime()` mean to you? Does it mean 1/1/0001? or does it mean DateTime.Now? Or something else? You're missing a huge piece of context at the moment.

Comment: @code4life it was an example.

Comment: Still doesn't answer my question - what exactly are you trying to accomplish...?

Comment: @ASh: then we're talking about a span of time (`TimeSpan`), not calendar date time (`DateTime`). So the entire code posted in the question is invalid.

Comment: @code4life, yes, indeed, it is more clear in late edit

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll be ajusting the question as the doubts appear.

Comment: @code4life I think now the question makes more sense, thanks for helping it get better.

Comment: @DaveZych it would have to build a proper object date for it, just that time without right now time. If needed it can be minutes, hours, days, months etc. It has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx).  You don't want a date.

> Represents a time interval.

```
var ticks = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0).Ticks;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But before the hours and minutes variables were parse into Int.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse a three digit hour to a `DateTime` value. You could parse the minute value to a `DateTime` but it makes more sense to use integer values for the compontents:

```
int hour = Int32.Parse(dateTimeHour);
int minute = Int32.Parse(dateTimeMinute);
```

You can't use the hour value to create a `DateTime` value, but you can create the `DateTime` value first and then add the hours. Example:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, minute, 0).AddHours(hour);
```

#### Edit:

If you just want the ticks as result, you can calculate that directly from the hours and minutes:

```
long ticks = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 600000000L;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.